# Getting sum of int cells from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have four dataframes with the same columns and a column "Area" which is consistent across the 4 dfs.

```
AREA     NUM1   NUM2
london   10     10

AREA     NUM1   NUM2
london   5      5
```

The output which i want to see in my new data frame is

```
Area     NUM1   NUM2
london   15     15
```

i have been try doing simple

```
dfTotal = df1 + df2
```

but what it is doing is giving me londonlondon for the area

Comment: There is only one non numeric column?

Comment: @jezrael yes there is only one which is the area there are more numeric columns but i just used two as an example

Comment: So how working my solution?

Comment: Thanks that has sorted it out for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create index by column `AREA` for alignment before sum with [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
dfTotal = ((df1.set_index('AREA').select_dtypes(np.number) +
            df2.set_index('AREA').select_dtypes(np.number))
               .reset_index())

print (dfTotal)
     AREA  NUM1  NUM2
0  london    15    15
```

General solution:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
L = [x.set_index('AREA').select_dtypes(np.number) for x in dfs]

dfTotal = pd.concat(L).sum(level=0).reset_index()
print (dfTotal)
     AREA  NUM1  NUM2
0  london    15    15
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to concat the 4 dataframes, and then run a groupby/pivot_table to get the result. The upside on that is as you add more dataframes (if you will need to), the code won't change that much